# jQuery phone number masking with Regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to mask the phone number into a region specific format.

```
$("input:text[name=phone_number]").keyup(function() {
    var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "($1) $2-$3");

        $(this).val(number);
});
```

The problem I am having with the script above is that regex is waiting for 3 numbers before it replaces the value in the input field.

And additionally I have to press enter for the effects to take place.

---

Is there a way I can make `(\d{3})` this more dynamic. For example even if I've entered only 1 digit it should still display `(0  )`.

And then I continue entering `(05 )`... and so on...to a format that looks like this `(051) 000-000`?

I don't want to use additional plugins. I know there are many out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple mask, check:

```js
$("input[name=phone_number]").keydown(function(e) {
    var actualValue = e.key;
    var baseMask = '(###) ###-###';
    var valueInput = this.value.match(/\d/g);
    if (actualValue !== 'Backspace' && /[^\d]/.test(actualValue)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (actualValue === 'Backspace') {
        if (!valueInput) {
            return false;
        }
        valueInput.pop();
        actualValue = '#';
    }
    var numsValues = valueInput ? valueInput.concat(actualValue) : [actualValue];
    $.each(numsValues, function() {
        baseMask = baseMask.replace(/\#/, this);
    });
    $(this).val(baseMask);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="phone_number">
```

Comment: Love it. Just the hashed mask doesn't work for me. It works in the stackoverflow preview. But not in my document. What could be causing that?

Comment: Maybe the selector, in my example is `input[name=phone_number]` but in yours is `input:text[name=phone_number]`, what version of jQuery uses ?

Comment: It's `Version 3.2.1`. `:text` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I know that but I dont think in other possible problem, the code is simple... In console dont appears anything warning or error ? The input element have another function attached to event ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#input").keyup(function() {
    var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

    number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
        if (p2.length < 1)
            return "(" + p1 + ") ";
        else if (p3.length < 1)
            return "(" + p1 + ") " + p2;
        return "(" + p1 + ") " + p2 + "-" + p3;
    });

    $(this).val(number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id=input placeholder="type your number">
```